# Couldn't find package "XXX" on the "npm" registry

Tags: node.js, npm

I am having problems with `yarn` install.

The package will install correctly with `npm install` but when installing with yarn the above error is produced. `error Couldn't find package "google-map-react" on the "npm" registry.`

## .npmrc

```
@companyname:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=476f....
```

I will admit, when removing the .npmrc file the error is still there. Which makes me think this must be some issue.

I also am making the assertion that the following command simply creates the `.npmrc` file in my home directory? `npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --scope=@companyname`

I would ideally like to be able to install external NPM packages.

Comment: I believe it may be something to do with needing to do the `npm login` on the correct version as node was installed on. If you upgrade or change with nvm then you will see this error?

Comment: Humm after multiple tries, I do not believe this fixed it :(

Answer (score 4):

So I've found it after too long. I was seeing this error as yarn was using its config to connect to npm: `npm.github.registry`

I had previously worked in EuroStar which had their own private npm registry. Thus it was failing on simple packages because there npm is completely locked down.

So simple command:

```
yarn config delete registry
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using yarn, npmrc files are not being read no more:

Yarnrc files (named this way because they must be called .yarnrc.yml) are the one place where you'll be able to configure Yarn's internal settings. While Yarn will automatically find them in the parent directories, they should usually be kept at the root of your project (often your repository). Starting from the v2, they must be written in valid Yaml and have the right extension (simply calling your file .yarnrc won't do).

https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#npmRegistries

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3612

https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration

https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc